# Run a loop n times

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a program that will calculate a number entered by the user multiplied by 2.

I realised I need a for loop so that the Value will increment by 1 and multiple by 2

The problem is I want to know how to run this loop **only 10 times**
- at the current moment it will run for ever and I had to place an if statement to break out of the loop if the value reaches 50.

```js
//prompt user to enter number
let value = prompt("Enter A number");
//user entered number will loop through while output will show multiples //of 2
for (value;; value++) {
  value2 = value * 2;
  document.write(`${value} multiply 2 -> ${value2}`);
  document.write('<br>');
  //i placed this if statement to break out of the for loop as it //will run forever
  if (value > 50) {
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i< 10; i++)` change the `for` loop, and make all the operations needed, inside the loop

Comment: `for (value;; value++)` makes no sense. The first `value` doesn't do anything, then you've omitted the loop condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use a counter variable to keep a check on number of iterations. I am guessing you want to increase value by 1 after each iteration. You can do something like this:

```js
  //prompt user to enter number
    let value = prompt("Enter A number");
 //user entered number will loop through while output will show multiples //of 2
    for (var i=1;i<=10; i++) {
      value2 = value * 2;
      document.write(`${value} multiply 2 -> ${value2}`);
      document.write('<br>');
      //i placed this if statement to break out of the for loop as it //will run forever
      value++;

    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <!--
<script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
-->
</head>

<body></body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Dij, this is what i wanted!! i didn know of adding value++ in the for loop and using the i variable .

Answer (score -2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Multiple By 2</h2>

<input type="text" id="num"/>

<button onclick="multiply()">multiply by 2</button>

<script>
function multiply() {
    var number = document.getElementById("num").value;
    for(i=1;i<11;i++){
       console.log(number*i);

    }  
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But...this doesn't multiply the numbers by 2.